# eclipseで、gitプラグインのせいで行番号が見えない

Tags: git, eclipse

eclipseをgitと連携させたんですが、そのせいで行番号表示が見えなくなってしまって困っています。
画像だと3行目だけかろうじて紫に侵食されていません。

[image: 行番号が見えないイメージ]

変更を加えた行の行番号のところが紫色に変わるみたいなのですが、ちょっと不便です。

まずは設定で[一般]>[外観]>[色とフォント]を開き、Gitの項目内で色が変更できる項目は全て試してみたのですが、どの項目でも改善は見られませんでした。
[一般]>[外観]>[ラベル装飾]の中にあるGitのチェックボックスをつけたり外してみたりもしたのですが、行番号の所にはなんの影響もありませんでした。
[チーム]>[Git]の中の項目にも、それらしい項目を見つける事ができませんでした。

この部分の色の設定はどこで変えればいいのでしょうか？

環境は以下の通りです。
PC:MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014)
OS:macOS Sierra Ver. 10.12.6
eclipse:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500
Git:
Git integration for Eclipse 4.6.1.201703071140-r    org.eclipse.egit.feature.group  Eclipse EGit

---

一応、設定内の[一般]>[エディター]>[テキスト・エディター]を開いて、
[外観色のオプション]というところで[行番号の前景]の色を白などに変更すれば、行番号が白になり見えるようにはなるんですが、こういうアプローチを求めているのではなくて・・・
それともこうするのが最適解なんでしょうかね？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

最適解だと思います。

行番号の文字の色と変更行の背景色が同じ色で被ってしまったということであれば、どちらかの色を変えるしかないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうですか・・・どちらかといえば変更行の背景色を変更したい所なのですが、そっちはやはり難しいのでしょうか？

Comment: 設定に無いとすれば、変更行の背景色は固定値なんでしょうね。